# Is Node.js stream Duplex only there for subclassing?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a need in my code to simultaneously push out live streaming data to multiple clients that comes from a single source, but the clients *may* or *may not* be all connected to receive the live stream data. So I need to be able to simultaneously write to a file for late receiving clients.

So I was thinking about using Stream.Duplex classes that I can write to as data comes in that can be read by the assigned clients. However, when I create a new Duplex class and try and write data to it or hook the "data" event I get

> [Error: not implemented]

errors. So is the Stream.Duplex class only there to subclass? Is there an easier way to use it?

My test code:

```
var duplex = require( 'stream' ).Duplex;

var myDuplex = new duplex();

myDuplex.on( 'error', function( error ) {
    console.log( error );
} );
myDuplex.on( 'data', function( buffer ) {
    console.log( "Received [%s]", buffer.toString( 'utf8' ) );
} );

// Push the derta
myDuplex.write( new Buffer( "Hello data.", 'utf8' ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Duplex` is for subclassing.  All it means is a stream that is both writable and readable; it says nothing about any sort of relation between the two.

What you are most likely looking for is the [PassThrough Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough).  `Transform` is a more specific type of `Duplex` in which the readable part is calculated from the writable, and `PassThrough` is the trivial implementation of a `Transform`.